# Python socket data-rate 10x slower than throughput on NIC

Tags: python, sockets

I've been sketching some test code for a file transfer using a TCP socket in python (3.9 - Win10 x64). When I run the code below the NIC throughput in task manager increases by about 100Mb/s (goes back down when the socket is broken). The data rates on the hard drives and the measured rate in the code seem to indicate that the actual transfer rate of the intended data is about 11Mb/s. First the code and next some more info about what I have been trying:

Client

```
import socket, os, sys
from threading import Thread
from time import monotonic

file_send = r'PATH TO FILE'

stats = os.stat(file_send)
print(stats.st_size)


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as client_soc:
    client_soc.connect(('192.168.1.88', 6325))
    client_soc.sendall(str(stats.st_size).encode('utf-8'))
    client_soc.recv(10)

    buffer_size = 1024 * 32
    #client_soc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, buffer_size)

    with open(file_send, 'rb') as f:
        bytes_read = 0
        s_time = monotonic()
        check_in = s_time

        while bytes_read < stats.st_size:
            read = f.read(1024*1024*10)
            mono = monotonic()
            t_diff = mono - s_time
            if mono - check_in > 10:
                print('{:,.0f} Kb/s'.format((bytes_read / 1024) / t_diff))
                check_in = mono
            client_soc.send(read)
            bytes_read += len(read)
        print('Done sending')
```

Server

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


class DLThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, bind_address, port, file_recv):
        super(DLThread, self).__init__()
        self.life_switch = True
        self.bind_address = bind_address
        self.port = port
        self.file_recv = file_recv

    def run(self) -> None:
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as listen_doc:
            listen_doc.bind((self.bind_address, self.port))
            listen_doc.listen()
            print('listening')
            client_conn, addr = listen_doc.accept()
            with client_conn:
                print('Connected')
                data = client_conn.recv(1024)
                size = int(data)
                print('File size: {}'.format(size))
                client_conn.sendall(b'k')

                gotten = 0
                percent_inc = 0.1
                percent_chunk = percent_inc * size
                thresh = percent_inc * size
                with open(self.file_recv, 'wb') as f:
                    while gotten < size:
                        data = client_conn.recv(1024*1024*5)
                        f.write(data)
                        gotten += len(data)
                        if gotten > thresh:
                            print('{:.0%} Complete'.format(gotten / size))
                            thresh = int(gotten // percent_chunk) + percent_chunk

    def pull_the_plug(self):
        self.life_switch = False
        self.join()


bind_addr = input('Bind Address: ')
port = int(input('port: '))
file_location = input('fileloc: ')

dl = DLThread(bind_addr, port, file_location)
dl.start()
print('Started')
dl.join()
```

I tried changing the buffer sizes ad using send / sendall. I also tried to have the client wait for a (redundant - I think) acknowledgement from the server at each chunk.

I took a look at the traffic in wireshark and I am seeing messages that appear to be padded with a bunch of 0s appended. I am not sure if this is a clue or not.

I can't think of why there would be so much overhead on the network interface. It feels weird just throwing all the data into the socket and letting the API do everything else but this is what many other people have done in their examples.

Sometimes with posts like this people recommend using a different tool. I just want to make it clear that I am not really trying to get this file transfer to work, I just want to understand why this is happening so I can learn something.

Comment: If my brain isn't asleep still from lack of coffee, your code shows megabytes per seconds while the NIC throughput probably shows megabits. Should give a factor of 8 difference which would make the numbers more reasonable.

Comment: That is a very good point. I will look into it. It would be kinda funny if I wasted the past hour wracking my brain over a classic gotcha like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very specific example of a common mistake, I'll confirm the answer here. Joachim Isaksson is correct. Task Manager reports network traffic in orders of bits/second not bytes/second. This is almost an order of magnitude different.

what learn? Pay attention to units and when things don't line up look for how the data could be related.